# dropping constraint throws error

Tags: postgresql

I have written my own script to generate a restore SQL file and one of the first tasks to do the restore is delete all the constraints that should be there. (Don't worry, I am limiting my script to ones that exist at the time of the backup.)

Here is a generic code snippet

```
ALTER TABLE ONLY data DROP CONSTRAINT IF EXISTS data_pkey;
```

Testing it on my own development environment it works as expected.  However, running it on the production server that same code throws an error:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "EXISTS"
LINE 1: ALTER TABLE ONLY data DROP CONSTRAINT IF EXISTS data_pkey;
```

If the `IF EXISTS` part is removed and the syntax is:

```
ALTER TABLE ONLY data DROP CONSTRAINT data_pkey;
```

the script runs without a problem.

I checked postgres.org under the ALTER TABLE section and my syntax is valid.

Comment: Versions of both installations? The `IF EXISTS` was introduced in Postgres 9.2.

Comment: IF EXISTS has to have been introduced before 9.2 for my development environment runs 9.1.11.  But I think you answered the question.  Querying the version through phpPgAdmin on the production server and it is merely 8.4, not 9.1 as documentation led me to believe,

Comment: Yes, my mistake - it's 9.0 and not 9.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a workaround for old versions you can either:

- Unconditionally drop the constraint and trap the error; or
- Check `information_schema` or the `pg_catalog` for the constraint, and only drop it if you find it already exists.

Comment: Nice anticipation of my follow-up question:  Since I can not use `IF EXISTS` because of the version as 8.4, how do I deploy the script?  :-)  Thanks for the answer